# how to use auth and authToken together with artifactory?

Tags: npm, artifactory

I have problem authenticating artifactory on both local and CI environments with `.npmrc`:

local config works only with `_authToken`

```
@render:registry=https://artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm/
//artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm/:_authToken=${JFROG_AUTH_TOKEN}
//artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm/:always-auth=true
//artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm/:email=myemail@corpname.io
```

CI works only with `_auth`

```
@render:registry=https://artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm/
//artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm/:_auth=${JFROG_AUTH_TOKEN}
//artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm/:always-auth=true
//artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm/:email=myemail@corpname.io
```

I've tried adding both hoping it will take whatever is compatible with env

```
@render:registry=https://artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm/
//artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm/:_authToken=${JFROG_AUTH_TOKEN}
//artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm/:_auth=${JFROG_AUTH_TOKEN}
//artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm/:always-auth=true
//artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm/:email=myemail@corpname.io
```

this didn't help, what else can I do to have consistent setup?

as far as I understood env difference is that one of them uses `npm login` and another one `basic auth`, but what is responsible for this? both envs use same node version and how do I sync the setup is unclear for me

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
curl -u %ARTIFACTORY_USER%:%ARTIFACTORY_KEY% https://artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/auth > ~/.npmrc
echo '@render:registry https://artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/components-npm' >> ~/.npmrc
npm config set registry https://artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/mirror-npmjs-org
npm config set @render:registry https://artifactory.corpname.io/artifactory/api/npm/components-npm
```

Adjust the lines for linux if needed.